# jquery sliding scrolling .animate div keeps going too far over the top of the footer information

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Thanks in advance for any help.
I have a sliding div with jquery .animate, div set with absolute position, I need to stop the sliding div when it gets to a certain point on the page because it just keeps going over the footer div. To add to the difficulty there is another div which is expandable because there are hidden divs with "see more" "less" buttons on the page. I perhaps need something like sliding div stop 800px from the bottom of the page, it will mean it stops sliding and goes off the top of the page right at the bottom. Hope that makes sense.
[Here is the page on a test domain](http://esdaledesigns.com/christmas-menu-lunch-dinner.php) That isn't the real website so if you reading this at any point in the future that wont work, it will be on [The Stockwell](http://thestockwellcolchester.com/).

```
    $().ready(function() {
    var $scrollingDiv = $("#right");

    $(window).scroll(function(){            
        $scrollingDiv
                            .stop()
            .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + -20) + "px"}, "slow" );         
    });
});
```

Again, thanks to anyone in advance for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
$().ready(function() {
    var $scrollingDiv = $("#right");

    $(window).scroll(function(){   
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < limit) {
            $scrollingDiv.stop()
            .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + -20) + "px"}, "slow" );    
        }     
    });
});
```

where you can set limit as you like.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks sidharth, really appreciate your quick straightforward help. Thank you. :)